# PySpark: Filter all rows that contain only NULL values

Tags: pyspark, databricks

Let's assume I've got a dataframe 'df' that contains a couple of rows which only consist of null values. How do I filter these rows?
I'd like to do something like the following which resembles what can be done with the select method:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.filter(*[col(column).isNull() for column in df.columns])
```

Of course, I somehow need to tell the filter method that all these conditions should be applied in combined with "AND" such that it knows that it should be like

```
df.filter((col(column1).isNull()) & (col(column2).isNull()) & ...)
```

Is there a nice solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use python's `reduce` to chain the conditions

```py
from functools import reduce

cond = reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, [func.col(c).isNull() for c in data_sdf.columns])

data_sdf.filter(cond)
```

Comment: one could also use `data_sdf.dropna('all')` instead of the above.